# Cleaning up and optimizing JavaScript code to check if an object contains a key that is present in a map

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code. It checks to see if the object contains the key where the key is present in the map.

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(2, 'test1');
myMap.set(3, 'test1');
let cellToHighLight = [];
let contanins = false;
for (let a = 2; a <= 5; a++)
  cellToHighLight.push({
    'rowId': a,
    'column': a++
  });
for (const key in cellToHighLight) {
  if (myMap.has(cellToHighLight[key].rowId)) {
    contanins = true
    break;
  }
}
console.log(contanins)
```

My code is working, but I am striving to write cleaner, more optimal code. Can anyone suggest a cleaner way to write this code and/or a more optimized form?

Comment: Use `Set`. Make a set of all the keys of `myMap`, make a set of the `rowId` values in `cellToHighLight`. Then test the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: Too bad Javascript doesn't have a native function to test intersection between two sets, so it still has to be hand-done.

Answer (score 2):

The Map() constructor can take an array of pairs, so you can set its starting values in one go.

A little whitespace can go a long way to visually separate different parts of your code.

I won't focus too much on your first for loop, as it looks like it was mainly meant to set up dummy values, but I will mention this: Avoid modifying your looping variable outside the actual for loop. If you want it to step by 2, just change `a++` to `a+=2` inside your for loop. (Also, I would rename "a" to "i" - i's a more standard looping variable name).

I would recommend staying away from `for in`, especially with arrays, it has some unexpected issues (like iterating out of order), and there's always another way to do it. In this case, `for (const value of cellToHighLight)`

What you're basically doing with that last for loop is "looking for something'. [yourArray.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [yourArray.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will do this for you. Go to that link and familiarize yourself with some of the other array methods available, they come in handy.

Here's a rewrite that applies the above suggestions.

```js
// setup variables

const myMap = new Map([
  [2, 'test1'],
  [3, 'test1']
]);

let cellToHighLight = [];
for (let i = 2; i <= 5; i+=2)
  cellToHighLight.push({
    rowId: i,
    column: i
  });

// search

let contanins = !!cellToHighLight.find(({ rowId }) => myMap.has(rowId));
console.log(contanins);
```